# round number to 2 decimal places

Tags: tcl, rounding

I need to round a number to two decimal places.
Right now the following rounds to the nearest integer I guess

```
puts [expr {round($total_rate)}]
```

If I do something like below it does not work. Is there another way around?

```
puts [expr {round($total_rate,2)}]
```

Comment: You can't round floating point to any number of decimal places greater than zero. It doesn't have decimal places. It has binary places, and they are incommensurable. You need to use a decimal radix, typically via a formatter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
expr {double(round(100*$total_rate))/100}
```

example

```
% set total_rate 1.5678
1.5678
% expr {double(round(100*$total_rate))/100}
1.57
% set total_rate 1.4321
1.4321
% expr {double(round(100*$total_rate))/100}
1.43
```

Comment: `proc tcl::mathfunc::roundto {value decimalplaces} {expr {round(10**$decimalplaces*$value)/10.0**$decimalplaces}}; expr {roundto($total_rate, 2)}`

Answer (score 17):

The simplest way to round to a specific number of decimal places is with `format`:

```
puts [format "%.2f" $total_rate]
```

Be aware that if you're using the rounded value for further calculations instead of display to users, most values that you print using rounding to *X* decimal places will not have an exact representation in binary arithmetic (which Tcl uses internally, like vast numbers of other programming languages). It's best to reserve rounding to a specific number of DPs to the point where you're showing values to people.

Answer (score 3):

```
puts [format "%.2f" $total_rate]
```

By using format, we can see the result in output but how to use the same value in the program, i.e., we can see  1.448 as 1.45 in the output but can we use 1.45 in the program then.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear whether the original question "I need to round a number" really was "I need to print out a rounded-off value of a number".  The latter is really best answered with a `[format ...]`, but the former could be interpreted as a need for a number of significant digits, i.e. how to adjust the number itself, and not just to format the printout string. I think the only answer that serves this purpose so far is the elegant one [Donal Fellows](https://stackoverflow.com/users/301832/donal-fellows) has provided. However, for "significant digits" instead of "digits after the decimal" I think a small modification is in order: get the number to be between 1 and 10 first (or between 0.1 and 1, if that is your convention), **then** trim the number of digits after the decimal. Without that, something like `roundto(0.00000001234567,4)` will get you a zero.

```
proc tcl::mathfunc::roundto {value sigfigs} {
  set pow [expr ($sigfigs-1)-floor(log10($value))]
  expr {round(10**$pow*$value)/10.0**$pow}
  }
expr roundto(0.000000123456789,5)
```

produces a value rounded off to 5 significant figures:

```
  1.2346e-7
```